# Having ecryptfs not encrypting /home directory after first login

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, cryptsetup

I'm on Ubuntu 16.06 LTS server and I've encrypted my home with ecryptfs following this [procedure](http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/). So far so good.

What I like with ecryptfs is that it's possible to remotely reboot the machine and files are unencrypted on user login (not possible with Cryptsetup/LUKS and whole disk encryption).

Nevertheless, is it possible to have the user's home directory not being re-encrypted when he logs out? So that you just can't read things if the machine is stolen but it's possible to have cron tasks read and write from user's home.

Comment: No it is not possible. Just make a data directory somewhere to store scripts or other things your user does not need to encrypt.

Comment: I use this machine as a backup machine, so it's not much the backing scipts but the backed up data that must be encrypted…